Magento 2, RequireJS: r.js cannot parse ES6 syntax
I am maintaining Magento 2 store. Since we have issues with RequireJS preformance, I decided to try optimizing following this tutorial Advanced JS bundling.
I have problem on "Run the r.js optimizer" step. When I try to run the command, I get following error:
Error: Error: Parse error using esprima for file: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mytheme/pub/static/frontend/MyTheme/default/en_US/Amasty_Xsearch/js/wrapper.js
Error: Line 406: Unexpected token .
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:27695:47

Problem is that this file is using ES6 syntax and r.js cannot understand that. I tried manually fixing all those errors, but there are tons of 3rd party scripts, it's just not worth doing it that way.
Things I already tried:

setting optimize: 'none' in build.js

adding optimize=none when running command


What should I do?

Did you find a solution?
